# How can I Listen for something that occurs within the OS itself

Tags: java, actionlistener

For instance, I would like to have my program running in the background and when text is highlighted anywhere, my program will come alive into focus.

Similar to what TinyGrab does, it appears once the user makes a screenshot.

Comment: Uh oh... tread lightly my friend. Very ambitious question you got going on there, and I'm really curious about the answer. I think you need to embed C aswell.

Comment: what have you tried?  what OS are you running on?  please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: It would be for all major operating systems (mac, windows, android, iOS)

The question is merely to get an idea on where to start my research into building a bridge between the lower and higher languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very OS specific question you have there and can definitely not be done in native Java. If there is support for what you are looking for by the OS, you will definitely have to use a [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to write plain C code in order to have access to the low-level OS features provided in C.

Comment: Use JNA instead of JNI.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its a good idea to use a virtual machine to spy the host machine's ui ...

check for the host os/ui for the supported way to access user inputs and then call/execute/signal it somehow to the vm.